# Rate of change?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If the volume of a sphere increases at the rate of 6 cm$^3$/s, find the rate of increase in the surface area of the sphere at the instant when its radius is 4cm.

Can someone please explain how we move from knowing `dV/dt` to `dA/dt` ?

Comment: Can you express $A$ as a function of $V$? (Or, can you express both as a function of $r$, and then can you use that express $A$ as a function of $V$?)

Answer (score 3):

For a sphere, $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ and $A = 4 \pi r^2$.  Differentiating, you can find expressions for $dV$ and $dA$ in terms of $dr$.  Knowing the value of $dV$ lets you solve for $dr$, which you can plug into the expression for $dA$.

Comment: It would be more proper to say you can find expressions for $\frac {dV}{dr}$ and $\frac {dA}{dr}$, then since you have $\frac {dV}{dt}$ you can find $\frac {dr}{dt}$ and then $\frac {dA}{dt}$ but the approach is correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan, oops, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Volume of sphere, $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$

Rate of change of volume, $\frac{dV}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}=6cm^3/s$

When $r=4cm,\ \frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{3}{32\pi}$

Now surface area, $A=4\pi r^2$

Hence $\frac{dA}{dt}=8\pi r\frac{dr}{dt}=32\pi \frac{3}{32\pi}=3cm^2/s$

Answer (score -1):

Volume(V) of a sphere of radius r is calculated by 4pr^3 /3 and surface area(A) by 4pr^2.

dV/dt = 4pr^2 × dr/dt. 
                     ( by chain rule)

dA/dt = 8pr × dr/dt

```
       = 2/r ×  4pr^2 × dr/dt

       = 2/r × dV/dt

       = 2/4×6 cm^2/s

       =3 cm^2/s.
```

Here p represent pi the ratio of circumference to diameter of a circle.